# what is the difference between argf.skip and argf.close?

Tags: ruby

Looking at the source for #skip the file is closed before moving to the next file. This is the behavior that #close is supposed to implement.  The doc suggests that the file should remain open when using #skip.

Answer (score -1):

Not much. there is one difference though: `skip` does nothing if there are no more files, `close` raises `IOError`.

Comment: The doc for #skip does not say anything about closing the current file. So why does #skip close it?

Comment: @Richard: Logically, skipping makes sense to close the file. There is no method to go backward, so it makes sense to dispose of the object.

Comment: Logically? I disagree. The behavior described in the DOC does not include closing the file. So it's not so logical.

Comment: @Richard: Let me try again. There is only a method to go forward, not backward, and therefore, a file you skip in ARGF will not be accessed again *from ARGF*, so it is closed to save resources. Make sense?

Comment: I do not need to go backward. I want to capture the ARGF.file so I can reuse it. AGAIN, my need has nothing to do with the fact that the documentation is either wrong or incomplete or the code is wrong.

Comment: Than get the file name and make a new file! Copy it! There are many things you can do.